# To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag

Tags: azure, terraform

Why do I get this error (sorry a newbee)
" To specify a working directory for the plan, use the global -chdir flag"

I have my tfvars file in a folder called `env-vars/dev.tfvars`. So when I run `Terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars` or `Terraform plan -var-file=env-vars\dev.tfvars` I would like to run those set variables .
The parent directory is TfTest which contains main.tf, variables.tf etc

I'm not sure I understand the working directory vs workspace when using Vscode
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your directory layout, which files are where, and where you are calling Terraform from

Comment: PS C:\Users\user1\docs\source\TFTest> 
tf located C:\tools\terraform.exe

Comment: Is the command that you are showing (`terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars`) exactly the command that you are running? No other arguments? And is that the complete error message?

Comment: Pretty much. I have uploaded the error

Comment: You are still not showing the command that you are calling. And "pretty much" is absolutely not true - you have left out the line with bold red text, which should really be the first thing you read.

Comment: Sorry Yes, I'm running that command. bear with me I'm trying to learn this at the same time. I've update the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this on my own using this code

> terraform plan -var-file="env-vars/dev.tfvars"

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `-var-file=` and `dev.tfvars`. That means terraform sees `dev.tfvars` as a separate argument, hence the big bold error message "**Too many command line arguments**".